# Ajax submission not working for same webform rendered multiple times on same page

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a content type called "FAQ" with teaser type display views page(Around 30 contents). I have created an ajax webform and rendering the form under each teaser content to collect user's feedback for the FAQ. When I submit the first webform it works fine. But when I try to submit other forms on the same page it just scrolls to the top of the page and shows the confirmation message on the first form.

I guess it is not working due to the same ajax wrapper ID being loaded for all the forms. Can someone please suggest the best option to render the same form multiple times?

[image]

Comment: It is due to reason that form is having same identity. Check for configuration where you can have multiple instances with different id.